# how to identify different user on twitter if i want to tweet on behalf of them using a single script through api?

Tags: php, twitter

i have an application which tweet on behalf of a user when user grant permission. but i want that user can schedule their tweet for future. For that i use cron job to run my script every minute. But i don't understand how to identify different user when script run and post? what credential is parmanently identify a user when making a api call?

this is my code segment to understand what i am doing:

```
    $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth('inBAC5z1EiCt8k6z32dqw','s8IK3HT8cWReb2YUSV8kTQvf3qANXwKZhCZORw5XAVg', $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_secret']);  
    $twitteroauth->post('statuses/update', array('status' =>$status));
```

Answer (score 0):

Save `$_SESSION['oauth_token']` and `$_SESSION['oauth_secret']` in a database and use the database values in your cron job.